# Show all Spring form errors on Velocity template

Tags: spring, validation, forms, spring-mvc, velocity

I've got an application using Spring MVC and Velocity.  On one of my forms, I want to show all errors related to the form at the top of the page.  I've figured out how to show errors related to one particular field (using the #springShowErrors macro), but I really want to have one large block of errors at the top of the form, instead of listing the errors next to each individual item.

I've done quite a bit of googling, and a few people have suggested something like

```
#if ($status && $status.errors.hasErrors())
#foreach( $error in $status.errorMessages )
<p>$error</p>
#end
#end
```

...but this gives me no output when placed just below the initial #springBind macro that attaches my command object to the form.  Putting #springShowErrors just after the #springFormInput macro for each field works fine, so I know my validator is running and generating errors.

Any ideas?  Have I missed something really silly?

Here's the complete form, with my non-working attempt just after the first #springBind

```
<form name="standardForm" id="standardForm" method="post" action="#springUrl("/requestAccess")">
            #springBind("accessRequest")
#if ($status && $status.errors.hasErrors())
#foreach( $error in $status.errorMessages )
<p>$error</p>
#end
#end

            <fieldset>

                  <label for="name">Name</label>

                  #springFormInput("accessRequest.name" " ")


                  <label for="company">Company</label> 

                  #springFormInput("accessRequest.company" " ")

                  <label for="title">Title</label> 
                  #springFormInput("accessRequest.title" " ")

                  <label for="email">Email</label> 

                  #springFormInput("accessRequest.email" " ")

                  <button  type="submit" value="send">Send</button>

             </fieldset>
         </form>
```

Thanks for any help or advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. There's no direct way I know of to get all the object error messages and field error messages in one aggregated list, however you can do this:

```
#springBind("bindName")
#if($status.errors.hasErrors())
    ## Global error messages
    #foreach($e in $status.errorMessages)
        <p>${e}</p>
    #end
    ## Field error messages
    #foreach($f in $status.errors.fieldErrors)
        #springBind("bindName.${f.field}")
        #foreach($e in $status.errorMessages)
            <p>${e}</p>
        #end
    #end
#end
```

Not so clean, but it works.